# Possible to have local costmap aligned with base link?

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering if there is an option to have the local costmap aligned with your robot?
My point is that if you have a car-like robot which moves mostly forward and cant turn in place, most of the space in a local costmap is useless.

So I would reduce the length of the costmap behind the robot and also the width but would increase the length in front of the robot.

Is there already such an option from which I am not aware?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278509/possible-to-have-local-costmap-aligned-with-base-link?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2018-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Costmaps are generally aligned to a semi-fixed frame like odometry for efficiency of moving the costmap. If the costmap needs to move forward , the operation of moving rows is much quicker than calculating a transform and applying that to existing costmap data. The [code is not even set up to monitor rotations](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/kinetic-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d.cpp#L260). So I think the short answer is no.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2